# Generating HTML from PL/SQL

Tags: html, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Hello_world2
IS
BEGIN
    HTP.htmlopen;
    HTP.headopen;
    HTP.Title ('You knew it was coming...');
    HTP.headclose;
    HTP.comment ('This phrase is in every computer book.');
    HTP.Bodyopen (cattributes => 'body bgcolor=blue');
    HTP.Print ('And here it is .... Hello, World!');
    HTP.bodyclose;
    HTP.htmlclose;
END;
```

How can I output this to an HTML file? I have tried as shown below:

```
spool report.htm
exec hello_world2;
spool off
exit
```

But I am getting error as shown below:

```
    ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.OWA_UTIL", line 356
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.HTP", line 1368
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.HTP", line 1443
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.HTP", line 1735
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.HTP", line 72
    ORA-06512: at "T416493.HELLO_WORLD2", line 4
    ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Getting the error on first execution, not subsequent ones. No idea why. Generating a HTML page from PL/SQL however...

Comment: @Sathya: I am able to create procedure ,but am not able to create html ,is there any other method to generate html from pl sql ?

Comment: At the risk of sounding unhelpful, why? Generating html in an oracle procedure has all my code-smell senses tingling. Surely, there is a better place to put your html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you would call `owa_util.showpage` to spool the contents out.
Dan has a nice overview of the usages [Oracle OWA_UTIL](http://psoug.org/reference/owa_util.html)
There is something funny about this, it should run from sqlplus but I think it expects to be called from mod_plsql, using a web browser.

If you really only want te generate static web pages, you can also use plain old dbms_output to do that. Otherwise, it might be smarter to take a look at [Oracle Apex](http://apex.oracle.com/i/index.html) or maybe even [a very nice and capable alternative for Oracle Apex, Formspider](http://theformspider.com/)

Comment: :how old dbms_output works , i have created a simple begin   end block  ,inside that i have put variaus dbms_output statement ,but when i spool that block ,i get an output `PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.`

Comment: @Ollie: Thanks Ollie it works ,but why i am getting this error can you help ,i am trying to avoid hardcoding of tags in my code .

Comment: For now I think it is fastest to code your most used tags as functions/procedures like htp package does, using dbms_output. In 11g many restrictions on dbms_output are gone.

Answer (score 1):

> ORA-06512: at "SYS.OWA_UTIL", line 356

Did you try to see what's there? :-)
That line has 
 `for i in 1..owa.num_cgi_vars`
so you're trying to run cgi-aware code in non-cgi environment.
The owa.num_cgi_vars variable is NULL.

begin 
        for i in 1..null
        loop
                null;
        end loop;
end;

will give you the same ORA-06512.

Answer (score 0):

You need to init the CGI with owa.init_cgi_env

See http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:347617533333

It worked for me where everything else failed.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.
I inserted another dad-profile and it worked like a charm :)
Somehow the old dad-profile got rotten.

-- as xdbadmin or sys (mpl_user is of course schema where packages reside):
exec dbms_epg.create_dad('new_dad', '/my_db/*');
exec dbms_epg.set_dad_attribute('new_dad', 'database-username', 'UUSSEERR'); -- username in uppercase
grant execute on dbms_epg to uusseerr;

-- as user (uusseerr):
exec dbms_epg.authorize_dad('new_dad');

Answer (score 0):

Below code will print the html page formed using stored procedure.

```
    set serveroutput on;
    declare
        vNames  owa.vc_arr;
        vValues owa.vc_arr;
    begin
        htp.init;
        vNames(1) := 'REQUEST_PROTOCOL';
        vValues(1)  := 'HTTP';

        owa.init_cgi_env(
        num_params => 1,
        param_name => vNames,
        param_val  => vValues );

        test_package.proc_call; --procedure where html pages are formed using htp.p
        owa_util.showpage;
    end;
    /
```